# how to remove repetition on inner join on two table

Tags: mysql, database, repeat

I have two tables: A "parent" table `tableA` and a "child" table with many rows for each parent row, like this:

```
tableA
 a_id     email          role
    1     abc@gmail      admin
    2     abc2@gmail     teacher
    3     abc2@gmail     student

tableB
 b_id    a_id    meta_key       meta_value
    1       1      first name       
    2       1      last name        
    3       1      mobileno        989898989
    4       2      first name       
    5       2      last name        singh
```

I want data with columns:

```
a_id, email, first_name, last_name, mobileno
```

But I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Please take a moment and a) fix your formatting, and b) include the query you have already tried.

Comment: You mean GROUP BY some field you want them grouped on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join to the "child" table once for every different row you need data from:

```
select
    a.a_id,
    email,
    b1.meta_value as first_name,
    b2.meta_value as last_name,
    b3.meta_value as mobileno
from tablea a
left join tableb b1 on b1.a_id = a.a_id
    and b1.meta_name = 'first name'
left join tableb b2 on b2.a_id = a.a_id
    and b2.meta_name = 'last name'
left join tableb b3 on b3.a_id = a.a_id
    and b3.meta_name = 'mobileno'
```

I chose *outer* (ie `left`) joins so you would still get the row from tablea even if some corresponding data is missing from tableb.

---

The column names that start with "meta" don't contain metadata, they contain plain ordinary data. "metadata" is data *about* the data, not "extra" data; eg a mobile phone number does not describe other data values.

You should consider renaming the columns to "data_name" and "data_value".